# I can't identify empty cells from an xlsx on import in my Excel function in C#

Tags: c#, import, xlsx

I am trying to import an `.xlsx` file into the database. I have a problem inside the import function: I call a function that creates a list of the elements in a row, the list with each cell in each row, I cannot identify when some cells are empty.

Thank you in advance for your help and interest!

This is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
//using Excel Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;
//#using dracia dracu;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class zTool : Form
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        public zTool()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // pick a file/ chose a file
            string filePath = OpenFilePicker();

            //pun calea intr-un string
            if (filePath != null) 
            {
                // verific string ul sa nu fie null
                textBox1.Text = filePath;

                // completez casuta de path cu calea aleasa
            }
            else 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Alege un fisier de import!");
                //afisez mesaj de eroare in caz ca butonul a fost apasat insa nu a fost ales nici un fisier';
            }
        }

        public string OpenFilePicker()
        {
            //deschide fereastra de selectie document;
            OpenFileDialog filePicker = new OpenFileDialog();
            filePicker.Title = "Select a File";
            filePicker.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (filePicker.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return filePicker.FileName;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //check db connection button 
            //ShowProgressBar();
            // this is the connection string , with this one we connect via sqlConnection property from below
            string connectionString = "Data Source=192.168.180.15;Initial Catalog=Localize_Hercules;User ID=sa;Password=UniDB!Admin;";

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection successful!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection failed: Conexiunea nu s-a putut realiza. Verifica VPN ul! Eroare la conectare: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString2 = "Data Source=192.168.180.15;Initial Catalog=Localize_Hercules;User ID=sa;Password=UniDB!Admin;";
            ImportExcelFile(textBox1.Text, connectionString2);
        }

        public void ImportExcelFile(string filePath, string connectionString)
        {
            int nrDeRanduriInserate = 0;

            try
            {
                // Open the Excel file for reading
                using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, false))
                {
                    WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
                    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
                    Worksheet worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;

                    SheetData sheetData = worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

                    // Open a database connection
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        bool isFirstRow = true; // flag variable to skip the first row
                                                // Loop through each row in the Excel file
                        foreach (Row row in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
                        {
                            if (!isFirstRow) // check if this is not the first row
                            {
                                // Extract the values from each cell in the row
                                List<string> cellValues = GetCellValues(workbookPart, row);

                                // Insert the values into the database using parameterized queries

                                string sql = "INSERT INTO DICTIONARYIMP (ID, RESTEXT, TRANS01, TRANS02) VALUES (@Value1, @Value2, @Value3, @Value4)";
                                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                                {
                                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1", string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellValues[0]) ? DBNull.Value : (object)cellValues[0]);
                                    //MessageBox.Show(cellValues[0]);
                                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value2", string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellValues[1]) ? DBNull.Value : (object)cellValues[1]);
                                   // MessageBox.Show(cellValues[1]);
                                    //aici crapa;
                                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value3", string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellValues[2]) ? DBNull.Value : (object)cellValues[2]);
                                   // MessageBox.Show(cellValues[2]);
                                    //
                                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value4", string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellValues[3]) ? DBNull.Value : (object)cellValues[3]);
                                    //MessageBox.Show(cellValues[3]);
                                    nrDeRanduriInserate += command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    //command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                isFirstRow = false; // set the flag to false after reading the first row
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // 
                MessageBox.Show("Importul a fost efectuat! " + "S-au importat " + nrDeRanduriInserate.ToString() + " linii! " + "Cod eroare de confirmare: " + ex.Message);
                //de verificat de ce nu scap de string or bynary data pentru ultimul rand;
            }
        }

        private static List<string> GetCellValues(WorkbookPart workbookPart, Row row)
        {
            List<string> cellValues = new List<string>();

            foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
            {
                // here i need help to identify the empty cell;
                if (cell == null
                    // (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.InnerText) == true) 
                    // || 
                    // (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.CellValue) == true) ||
                    // (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.InnerText) == true) ||

                    // cell.InnerText == "" ||
                    // cell.CellValue == null ||
                    // cell.InnerText == null ||
                    // cell.CellValue.InnerText == ""
                    )
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("celula goala"+ cell.CellValue);

                   // Cell value is empty, add "null" to cell values list
                   cellValues.Add("null");
                }
                else
                {
                    string cellValue = cell.InnerText; // Define cellValue variable here

                    if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
                    {
                        var sharedStringTable = workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable;
                        int index = int.Parse(cellValue);
                        cellValue = sharedStringTable.ElementAt(index).InnerText;
                    }

                    cellValues.Add(cellValue);
                }
            }
            
            return cellValues;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Connection string to  database
            string connectionString = "Data Source=192.168.180.15;Initial Catalog=Localize_Hercules;User ID=sa;Password=UniDB!Admin;"; 

            // Name of the table we want to delete data from
            string tableName = "DICTIONARYIMP";

            try
            {
                //we connect to the database;
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    // Open the connection
                    connection.Open();
                    // Create a SQL command to delete all records from the table
                    string sql = "delete from " + tableName;
                    //execute the command
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    // Display a message indicating the data was deleted successfully
                    MessageBox.Show("Liniile din tabela DICTIONARYIMP au fost sterse!");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // afisez mesajele de eroare;
                MessageBox.Show("Eroare stergere date: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int nrDeRanduriUpdatate = 0;
            string connectionString = "Data Source=192.168.180.15;Initial Catalog=Localize_Hercules;User ID=sa;Password=UniDB!Admin;";

            try
            {
                //we connect to the database;
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    // Open the connection
                    connection.Open();
                    // Create a SQL command to delete all records from the table
                    string sql = "UPDATE FD   SET FD.TRANS02=FI.TRANS02  FROM DICTIONARY FD  INNER JOIN DICTIONARYIMP FI ON FD.ID=FI.ID AND  FI.TRANS02!='NULL' AND FI.TRANS02!='' AND FI.ID!=''";
                    //execute the command
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        nrDeRanduriUpdatate += command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        //command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    // Display a message indicating the data was deleted successfully
                    MessageBox.Show("Au fost sincronizate liniile din DICTIONARYIMP cu cele din DICTIONARY! Nr linii updatate: " + nrDeRanduriUpdatate);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // afisez mesajele de eroare;
                MessageBox.Show("Eroare sincronizare date: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Connect to your database
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 192.168.180.15; Initial Catalog = Localize_Hercules; User ID = sa; Password = UniDB!Admin; ");

            // Create a SQL query to retrieve data
            string query = "SELECT * FROM DICTIONARYIMP";

            // Create a SqlDataAdapter object to fill the DataGridView
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);

            // Create a DataTable object to hold the data
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            // Fill the DataTable with the data from the database
            da.Fill(dt);

            // Set the DataSource property of the DataGridView to the DataTable
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use the directive using Excel Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; but I failed to install the dll from the NuGet Package. I found the directives as an alternative:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
```

and I worked with the following properties to identify if the cell is empty:

```
if (cell == null
                 //(string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.InnerText) == true)
                 //||
                 //(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.CellValue) == true) ||
                 // (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.InnerText) == true) ||

                 // cell.InnerText == "" ||
                 // cell.CellValue == null ||
                 // cell.InnerText == null ||
                 // cell.CellValue.InnerText == ""
                 )
```